# Is it possible to mount (S3) file into AWS::ECS::TaskDefinition ContainerDefinition using cloudformation?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate, open-telemetry

I have this ECS cluster that is running task definitions with singular container inside each group. I'm trying to add some fancy observability to my application by introducing OpenTelemetry. Following the AWS'es docs I found https://github.com/aws-observability/aws-otel-collector which is the AWS version of OTEL collector. This collector needs a config file (https://github.com/aws-observability/aws-otel-collector/blob/main/config/ecs/ecs-default-config.yaml) that specifies stuff like receivers, exporters, etc. I need to be able to create my own config file with 3rd party exporter (also need to add my secret API key somewhere inside there - maybe it can go to secrets manager and get mounted as env var :shrug:).

I'm wondering if this is doable without having to build my own image with baked config somewhere inside purely using cloudformation (what I use to deploy my app) and other amazon services?

The plan is to add this container besides each other app container (inside the task definition) [and yeah I know this is overkill but for now simple > perfect]

Building additional image will require some cardinal changes to the CI/CD so if I can go without those it will be awesome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend to check a doc for AWS ADOT. You will find that it supports config variable `AOT_CONFIG_CONTENT` ([doc](https://aws-otel.github.io/docs/setup/ecs/config-through-ssm)). So you don't need a `config file`, only a `config env variable`. That plays very well with AWS ecosystem, because you can use `AWS Systems Manager Parameter Store` and/or `AWS Secrets Manager`, where you can store otel collector configuration ([doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/secrets-app.html)).

Answer (score 1):

You can't mount an S3 bucket in ECS. S3 isn't a file system, it is object storage. You would need to either switch to EFS, which can be mounted by ECS, or add something to the startup script of your docker image to download the file from S3.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you take a look at https://github.com/awslabs/mountpoint-s3. It was made GA recently; however, remember it will require some elevated security to run.